# Use `git commit -p` or `git add -p` with magit

Tags: magit

How do `git commit -p` in magit?

Not have this section in man page

Answer (score 12):

The status buffer will show the unstaged changes.  Move point to the
changes that you want to stage, and call `magit-stage` (<kbd>s</kbd>).
If you want to stage a subset of changes within a single hunk, you can
select the lines with the region before calling `magit-stage`.

See the ["Staging and unstaging" section](https://magit.vc/manual/magit/Staging-and-Unstaging.html#Staging-and-Unstaging) of the manual for more
information.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stage lines of codes you can do `magit-status`, then on one file in the list of unstaged files <kbd>d</kbd>, then I select the lines you want to stage, then <kbd>s</kbd>.

Comment: `d` runs `magit-diff-popup`. Why are you suggesting that?

Comment: @phils Presumably, the idea is to press "d d" to get to a magit diff and then select and stage the desired change and stage those with "s".  The answer could use a few more details though, IMO.

Comment: I expect you're right; but it's very odd (to my mind) to suggest firstly going to the status buffer and then opening a diff buffer, given that all the diffs are available *directly within the status buffer*. I can't imagine many people would do it that way.

Comment: @phils I use `magit-status` first because I like to see the list of unstage files and the one for already stage files. I go on one file changed in the unstage section then click `d`. I see all the changes for all the unstaged files. Then `C+space` to select to portion of code I want to stage, then `s`.  Does that makes sense to you?

Comment: @leontalbot you can see all the unstaged changes and use `C-SPC` selection from the status buffer too. Why do you want to go to the diff buffer?

Comment: @npostavs Oh, to stage lines of code instead of files. When a want to stage files then yes, but can you select lines inside status buffer?

Comment: Yes -- in exactly the same way.  Expand the file, select a region, and type `s` to stage the region.